# why find:'/root/Documents* is printed?

Tags: linux, bash

---

```
else
then
 files1=$(find /root/Documents/actualBACKUPpath/co* -type f | wc -l)
if [ $files1 = 6 ];
 then
 rm  -rv /root/Documents/folder6astmp/co*
 cp -v /root/Documents/actualBACKUPpath/co*
/root/Documents/folder6astmp/
  rm -rv /root/Documents/actualBACKUPpath/co*
echo other day operation success with actual backup path
  else
   files2=$(find /root/Documents/folder6astmp/co* -type f | wc -l)
 if [ $files2 = 6 ];
                then
echo we have nothing to do in tmp directoy success
                fi
  fi fi
```

when I am executing the above code the output which I am getting is

```
find: ‘/root/Documents/actualBACKUPpath/co*’: No such file or
directory

we have nothing to do in tmp directory success
```

it is working fine as expected but why the statement `find:'/root/Documents*` is printed?

Comment: Errors get transmitted on a different channel STDERR not inline with normal output STDOUT and unless you specifically capture errors in your script you will see them in the console when you are running your script

Comment: And if you don't want to see the errors, add " 2> /dev/null " before the pipes

Comment: @HermanB thanks it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that there are no files matching the pattern "co*" in the directory /root/Documents/actualBACKUPpath and the cp commmand is complaining about it.

Try running the script with the -vx options to get it to show you what it's doing:

```
bash -vx scriptname
```

Or add the same options into the script declaration on the first line of the script (temporarily):

```
#! /bin/bash -vx 
. . .
```

Comment: Really thank you .it works ..!